# Iterate four lists in different loop python

Tags: python, loops, iteration

I have these four prob. lists:

```
x1 = [1,0,0] ; prob. of No goal scored per timeslot.
x2 = [0,1,0] ; prob. of Home Team scoring per timeslot.
x3 = [0,0,1] ; prob. of Away Team scoring per timeslot.
y = [0.97, 0.02, 0.01]; constant prob. per timeslot.
```

I want the sum of squared difference (sse) of `x1` and `y` until a goal is scored. Then the `sse` is calculated by `x2` or `x3` and `y` depending on who scored first. Then it loops back to `x1` and `y` until a goal is scored again by either Team and so on...

```
Here is what I have attempted so far.

Total timeslot = 15.
Order of timeslot
Home_Goal_timeslot = 8th, 14th. i.e. at two different timeslots.
Away_Goal_timeslot = 11th
No_Goal = 12. i.e. number of timeslots 12


x1 = np.array([1,0,0])
x2 = np.array([0,1,0])
x3 = np.array([0,0,1])
y = np.array([0.97, 0.02, 0.01])

def sum_squared_diff(x1, x2, x3, y, k):
    for k in range(15):
        if k == 'No_Goal':
           return sum((x1 - y)**2)
        elif k == 'Home_Goal':    
            return  sum((x2 - y)**2)
        else:
            return  sum((x3 - y)**2)





sum_squared_diff(x1, x2, x3, y, k=15)

Out[1912]: 1.9213999999999998     

print(sum((x1 - y)**2)**12, sum((x2 - y)**2)**2, sum((x3 - y)**2)**1)

    5.669391237529683e-35 3.6153219599999997 1.9213999999999998
add up to 5.5367219599999995
```

Why is the above solutions are different?
I prefer to add the `sse` after each timeslot and make a note when a goal is scored. So I can go back and add/subtract some `infinitesimal epsilon` to `y` values and measure the test...

```
This is the out come i want

 0.0014000000000000017,
 0.0014000000000000017,
 0.0014000000000000017,
 0.0014000000000000017,
 0.0014000000000000017,
 0.0014000000000000017,
 0.0014000000000000017,
 0.0014000000000000017,
 1.9014,
 0.0014000000000000017,
 0.0014000000000000017,
 1.9213999999999998,
 0.0014000000000000017,
 0.0014000000000000017,
 1.9014
```

Comment: First off you iterate `k` through integers up to 15 and then compare it to strings, `'No_Goal'` and `'Home_Goal'`.  
Secondly, what is your question?

Comment: @slybloty thank you for a time to look at the question. I want to add the sse after each iteration. Rather than doing sum((x1 - y)**2)**12.

Comment: So you're looking to print every result after each iteration. In that case check out my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What it seems to me you're trying to do is iterate through your `total timeslot` and if it matches any of your `Home_Goal` or `Away_Goal` then calculate as that.
What you're doing is this:

- Compare `int` to `str` (`k == 'No_Goal'`) which you'll be getting `False` pretty much all the time.
- End your loop at the first iteration by using `return` after your calculation.

Based on my understanding this is what you're looking for:

```
total_timeslot = 15
Home_Goal = [8, 14]
Away_Goal = [11]

def sum_squared_diff(x1, x2, x3, y):
    r1, r2, r3 = 0, 0, 0
    for k in range(total_timeslot):
        if k in Home_Goal:
            r2 += sum((x2 - y)**2)
        elif k in Away_Goal:
            r3 += sum((x3 - y)**2)
        else:
            r1 += sum((x1 - y)**2)
    return r1, r2, r3
```

### UPDATE:

After your updated question, seems that you want to `print` all results after each iteration, not only the end results. In that case you can add a `print` statement at the end of each loop and remove the incrementation.

### UPDATE 2:

Here's the code reflecting the changes:

```
def sum_squared_diff(x1, x2, x3, y):
    r1, r2, r3 = 0, 0, 0
    for k in range(total_timeslot):
        if k in Home_Goal:
            r2 = sum((x2 - y)**2)
        elif k in Away_Goal:
            r3 = sum((x3 - y)**2)
        else:
            r1 = sum((x1 - y)**2)
    print(r1, r2, r3)
```

Comment: Thank you @slybloty. This is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Solutions are different because last else-statement is True forever, because as @slybloty said, you compare `int k` with `str`. So your

```
def sum_squared_diff(x1, x2, x3, y, k):
        for k in range(15):
            if k == 'No_Goal':
               return sum((x1 - y)**2)
            elif k == 'Home_Goal':    
                return  sum((x2 - y)**2)
            else:
                return  sum((x3 - y)**2)
```

and

```
def sum_squared_diff(x1, x2, x3, y, timeslot):
    return sum((x3 - y)**2)
```

do same work

Comment: Thank you for your time @George.